# Reject / Bad Records Table in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I am looking for a reject link type of solution in a dedup scenario. For example in the following code:

```
MERGE 
temp.many_random t 
USING 
( SELECT DISTINCT * FROM temp.many_random WHERE d=CURRENT_DATE() ) 
ON FALSE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED 
BY SOURCE AND d=CURRENT_DATE() THEN DELETE 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT ROW
```

Can I replace `THEN DELETE` with something like `INSERT INTO TABLE` (different than the compare tables) so that we can capture these rejects and troubleshoot for pipeline analysis?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the problem, you want the result of a `MERGE` query to write to 2 different tables.

Since `MERGE` can't do that, I'll suggest to write 2 queries:

- One that does whatever the primary query is doing.
- A second almost identical one, but that writes the wrong records to a different table.